# PHP user-defined function issue with if clause

Tags: php

I have created this emptyFields function in my **functions.php** file and I am using require_once to require functions.php in my **validation.php** file.

```
function emptyFields($n, $e, $p, $cp) {
    $r;
    if ( empty($n) || empty($e) || empty($p) || empty($cp) ) {
        $r = true;
    } else {
        $r = false;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Now, I am using this if clause in the validation.php file to check for any empty fields.

```
if (emptyFields($name, $email, $pwd, $cpwd) !== false) {
    header("location: signup.php?errorid=emptyfields");
    exit();
}
```

**Note:** Before forwarding input to the `emptyFields` function, I also use the `inputSanitize` function which is as follows.

```
function inputSanitize($n) {
    $n = addslashes($n);
    $n = htmlspecialchars($n);
    $n = trim($n);
}
```

Apart from the above if clause, I also have other if clauses for email validation, password match etc.

**THE PROBLEM:** No matter what, It always executes this `emptyFields` function even when the input is properly provided. The next `if` clause in line, checks email format using another function, but it never gets executed. From my `signup.php` file, I input data and I get this query-string so I am assuming that only the emptyFields function gets executed.

> location: signup.php?errorid=emptyfields

I have tried using multiple `elseif` but nothing changes. I have checked the form inputs' names to see whether there is any error in taking input from form but everything seems fine there too. I am using XAMPP.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The line with just `$r;` doesn't do anything. Why do you have that?

Comment: The function looks fine to me. Add `var_dump($n, $e, $p, $cp);` to confirm that the variables contain what you expect.

Comment: It is a variable that I declared to modify later.

Comment: PHP doesn't require you to declare variables first.

Comment: Your `inputSanitize()` function is not returning anything. That would explain why anything it returns is considered to "empty".

Comment: @kmoser. Yes, I missed return $n there. Thanks you. I will check it and update you.

Comment: Your `emptyFields()` could be reduced to `return empty($n) || empty($e) || empty($p) || empty($cp)`

Comment: @kmoser. It works now that I have added the return keyword to inputSanitize(). Thank you for the help.

Answer (score -2):

try below instead of you own, remove the "else" condition which create the conditional tree and slow down when you execute alot of code.

```
function emptyFields($n, $e, $p, $cp) {
    $r = false;
    if ( empty($n) || empty($e) || empty($p) || empty($cp) ){
        $r = true;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: I have not tried this but I’m pretty sure that removing else will generate an error.